# can anyone tell me about the bandwidth weights?

Tags: bandwidth

I have read about Computing Bandwidth weights in Tor directory protocol, version 3. But I could not understand about how bandwidth weights are calculated. And since they appear only once in consensus, how they help in path selection by network balancing?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's easiest to explain this by example.  The following comes from the current consensus:

```
[...]
r TorNinurtaName AA8YrCza5McQugiY3J4h5y4BF9g TsD6f/8KF1h7Npm/w2vgkzDumjY 2014-05-08 23:15:06 151.236.6.198 9001 9030
s Fast Guard HSDir Named Running Stable V2Dir Valid
v Tor 0.2.3.25
w Bandwidth=238
p reject 1-65535
[...]
bandwidth-weights Wbd=849 Wbe=0 Wbg=4145 Wbm=10000 Wdb=10000 Web=10000 Wed=8301 Wee=10000 Weg=8301 Wem=10000 Wgb=10000 Wgd=849 Wgg=5855 Wgm=5855 Wmb=10000 Wmd=849 Wme=0 Wmg=4145 Wmm=10000
[...]
```

The `W??` numbers are the bandwidth weights.  For example, `Wgg` is the "Weight for Guard-flagged nodes in the guard position".

If your client were to consider that relay as a possible guard, it would multiply its consensus weight `238` with `Wgg`, so `238*5855=1393490`.  The reason is that this relay has the `Guard` flag, but not the `Exit` flag.  Your client does that for all relays and then selects one of them.

Comment: How do these bandwidhth weights are calculated? What would be the effect on these weights on increasing and decreasing the bandwidth of a relay?

Comment: Bandwidth weights are calculated by the directory authorities using a rather complex algorithm.  It's described in the directory protocol specification in Section 3.8.3. "Computing Bandwidth Weights" (https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/blob/HEAD:/dir-spec.txt#l2157).  If one of the bandwidth weights goes up (or down), all relays with the matching combination of relay flags will be more likely (or less likely) to be chosen by clients.

Comment: What is the meaning of "w Bandwidth=238"? Is it the advertised bandwidth of a relay? If I increase the bandwidthup and bandwidthdown value of my relay, then will this "w Bandwith value" increase?

Comment: "w Bandwidth=238" is the measured bandwidth of your relay: a subset of the directory authorities periodically run bandwidth measurements through your relay and then assign this value to it.  If you raise your bandwidth rate and burst, and if you make sure that your provider does not throttle your connection, then the measured bandwidth value should go up.  Give it a day or two for all directory authorities to measure your relay.

Comment: In the above consensus, lets say there is exit flag also, thus becoming guard+exit flagged node, then if the client were to consider that relay as a possible guard or exit, then would it multiply consensus weight 238 with Wgg or Wgd for guard position and with Wee or Wed for exit position? @karsten

Comment: That would be Wgd and Wed, respectively.  See the definitions here: https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/blob/HEAD:/dir-spec.txt#l1709

Comment: lets say if we have two routers having guard flag with one BW greater than other, then its obvious that client will choose node having BW greater for guard position. Then what is the use of Wgg here? Anyway, greater W * Wgg > smaller W * Wgg. Similarly for exit position also.  
Could you please explain me the role of bandwidth weights @karsten

Comment: Clients don't compare two relays and pick the faster one.  Clients go through the whole list of relays and pick one at random.  But not every relay is chosen with the same probability.  Instead, clients compute a weight for each relay.  Clients consider two values for this weight: the relay's consensus weight and the bandwidth weight corresponding to the relay's flag and the desired position.  The role of bandwidth weights is to prefer certain relays for certain positions and not overload them in other positions.  Please also re-read the relevant sections in the spec.