# How do bandwidth authorities measure bandwidth?

Tags: configuration, relays, directory, bandwidth

After reading a number of questions and resources on bandwidth measurements and life cycle of tor relays:

[can anyone tell me about the bandwidth weights?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/can-anyone-tell-me-about-the-bandwidth-weights)

[Can anybody explain the Advertised bandwidth, MaxAdvertisedBandwidth, Measured bandwidth, Bandwidth burst, RelayBandwidth rate?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3323/can-anybody-explain-the-advertised-bandwidth-maxadvertisedbandwidth-measured-b?rq=1)

https://blog.torproject.org/blog/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay

https://blog.torproject.org/blog/torflow-node-capacity-integrity-and-reliability-measurements-hotpets

http://fscked.org/talks/TorFlow-HotPETS-final.pdf

and the bandwidth weight specification:

https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt#2454

I am still not sure how bandwidth measurement is performed (from an implementation standpoint) by the bandwidth authorities. I have also found a library, [stem](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/examples/votes_by_bandwidth_authorities.html), that queries authorities and retrieves their measurement results.

Where should I look in the sources to find the code responsible for bandwidth measurement?

I am using version **0.2.8.0-alpha-dev (git-d015c70a118e4357)**. Grepping around the code for strings such as bandwidth, measurement, *bw* does not seem very lucrative(all results rely on handling consenus information).

Comment: https://gitweb.torproject.org/torflow.git/tree/NetworkScanners/BwAuthority see the README files